# instancemethod' object has no attribute 'return_value'

Tags: python

this is my code structure.

```
class manager:

class filterManager(manager):
    def __init__()
    #super class call etc..
    

class Client:
    def get_filter():
        filter = filterManager()
        return filter
    
 
@patch(filterManager)
class TestClient()
    filterManager.return_value.__init__.return_value = 'abc filter'
    obj = Client()
    val = obj.get_filter()
    assertEqual(val, 'abc filter')
```

I want to test Client class with mocked filterManager object.

But I am seeing this error
instancemethod' object has no attribute 'return_value'

How can I fix this?

Comment: `filterManager` isn't defined yet; the `patch` isn't applied until after the body of the `class` statement is evaluated and the class defined.

Comment: @chepner, thanks for quick response. What is the best way to test this scenario?